# ADODB Provider Can't be found

Tags: script, vbscript

Getting a `Provider Can't be found` error. This script is to rename a workstation on the domain while logging both the old name and new one in a csv file.

UPDATE: The script seems to complete but doesn't write anything to the .csv. It also doesn't rename the computer.

```
' RenamePC.vbs - Windows Logon Script.
' VBScript - Rename Workstation and Log Change
' Author Chris Collins
' Version 1 - July 2018
' ----------------------------------------------------------' 

Const JOIN_DOMAIN = 1
Const ACCT_CREATE = 2

Dim sCmpName,sUserType
Dim sUser,sPassword,sDomain,sOU
Dim strComputer,strSN,objWMIService,objBIOS,colSMBIOS,objShell

sUser = "administrator"
sPassword = "Password123"
sDomain = "Domain"
sOU = "OU=New Computers,DC=Domain,DC=k12,DC=az,DC=us"

' ************** Setup ************** 
' Folder where CSV File is located
' CSV file should have 1st field = oldname, 2nd field = newname with no header row
    strCSVFolder = "E:\VBScripts\TestFolder\"
' CSV filename
    strCSVFile = "computerrename.csv"
' Additional parameters to pass to NetDom command
        strNetDomParams = " /userd:"+sUser+" /passwordd:"+sPassword+" /usero:"+sUser+" /passwordo:"+sPassword+" /force "

'************************************ 

    'Part 1 - Acquire serial/service tag number
  strComputer = "."
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
  ' move the objShell creation to here to ensure it get created
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Set colSMBIOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_SystemEnclosure")
  For Each objSMBIOS in colSMBIOS
    strSN = objSMBIOS.SerialNumber
    If strSN <> "" Then exit For
  Next 

'Part 2 - Ask for Campus
  sCmpName = InputBox("Enter the Campus the computer is on (BB, DO, HCS, THS, WJM):", "Campus Name")
  If sCmpName = "" Then
    Wscript.Echo "Exiting script."
    Wscript.Quit
  End If

'Part 3 - Ask for Type
  sUserType = InputBox("Enter the User Type (CR, LAB, LIB, LP, NB, STAFF, TH). Insert other tags as well (ie -RF):", "User Type")
  If sUserType = "" Then
    Wscript.Echo "Exiting script."
    Wscript.Quit
  End If

'Part 4 - Assign computer name to serial/service tag number
  Dim oWMI, oCmp, oOS, sReturn

  Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
  For Each oCmp in oWMI.InstancesOf("Win32_ComputerSystem")
    strNewName = oCmp.Rename (+sCmpName+"-"+sUserType+"-"+strSN)
    If sReturn <> 0 Then
      Wscript.Echo "Rename failed.  Error = " & Err.Number & _
        vbcrlf & "Exiting script."
    Else
      Wscript.Echo "Rename successful."
      strNewName = oCmp.JoinDomainOrWorkgroup(sDomain, sPassword, _ 
        sDomain & "\" & sUser, sOU, JOIN_DOMAIN+ACCT_CREATE)
      If strNewName <> 0 Then
        Wscript.Echo "Join domain failed.  Error = " & Err.Number & _
          vbcrlf & "Exiting script."
  Else
    Wscript.Echo "Join domain successful."

'Part 4 - Setup ADO Connection to CSV file
        SET objShell = wscript.CREATEOBJECT("wscript.shell")
        SET cn = CREATEOBJECT("ADODB.Connection")
        SET rs = CREATEOBJECT("ADODB.Recordset")

        cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & strCSVFolder & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited"""

         rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & strCSVFile & "]", _
          cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

        DO until rs.eof
            strOldName = rs(0)
            strNewName = rs(1)
            strCmd = "cmd.exe /C netdom renamecomputer " & strOldName & " /newname:" & strNewName & strNetDomParams

            intReturn = objShell.Run(strCmd,intWindowStyle,blnWait)

            IF intReturn = 0 THEN
                wscript.echo "Renamed '" & strOldName & "' to '" & strNewName & "'"
            ELSE
                wscript.echo "Error renaming '" & strOldName & "' to '" & strNewName & "'" 
        END IF

        rs.movenext

        Set colComputers = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
        For Each objComputer in colComputers
            err = objComputer.Rename(strNewName)
        Next

For Each oOS in oWMI.InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
  sReturn = oOS.Reboot
Next
Loop
End If
'Step 5 - Reboot Computer
  Wscript.Echo "Rebooting computer..."
  Dim oShell 
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  'restart, wait 0 seconds, force running apps to close
  oShell.Run "%comspec% /c shutdown /r /t 0 /f", , TRUE
End If
Next
```

Comment: Out of interest, does it work if you call the script from the 32-bit cscript?  I assume you're on 64-bit Windows? E.g. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe script.vbs

Comment: Yes I'm on a 64-bit system. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: If you open an admin command prompt, then you can run:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\pathto\RenamePC.vbs`

Comment: Got ya, it ran without errors but didn't log anything in the csv.

Comment: Ok I ran debugging and get nothing. The script seems to complete but doesn't write anything to the .csv. Update code in original

Comment: I might be missing something, but is `Name` declared or assigned anywhere? `err = objComputer.Rename(Name)`

Comment: Yeah I changed it to `StrNewName`. Forgot to change it there. Fixed the code above, but it is not renaming or marking it in the .csv.

Comment: Update got the computer to actually be renamed, but it isn't writing in the CSV. Though it did give me the Join Domain failed error.